# Why would a symbol not be searched on the binary itself?

Tags: linker, binaryfiles, ld, elf, instrumentation

I have changed an ELF binary, and now I am trying to find out what I messed out.
My instrumented binary is called `mutatee_out` on the pasted text below.
The symbol it's saying that is undefined is indeed in the dynamic table, I have checked. And also with the right address on `.text` section.

So my question is: what are the reasons for an undefined symbol? (So I can examine what might have been gone wrong).

When I ran with `LD_DEBUG=symbols`, I noticed it's not looking up this symbol in the file itself, hence the undefined symbol. The other symbols are looked up on the file as you can see below too.

Any ideas? Why would this symbol not be searched on the binary itself?

```
 17405:     symbol=_ZTVSt11regex_error;  lookup in file=mutatee_out [0]
 17405:     symbol=_ZTVSt11regex_error;  lookup in file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0]
 17405:     symbol=__gxx_personality_v0;  lookup in file=mutatee_out [0]
 17405:     symbol=_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv;  lookup in file=mutatee_out [0]
 17405:     symbol=_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv;  lookup in file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0]
 17405:     symbol=_ZSt9terminatev;  lookup in file=mutatee_out [0]
 17405:     symbol=_ZSt9terminatev;  lookup in file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0]
 17405:     symbol=__gmon_start__;  lookup in file=mutatee_out [0]
 17405:     symbol=__gmon_start__;  lookup in file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0]
 17405:     symbol=__gmon_start__;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 [0]
 17405:     symbol=__gmon_start__;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]
 17405:     symbol=__gmon_start__;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 [0]
 17405:     symbol=__gmon_start__;  lookup in file=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0]
 17405:     symbol=__gmon_start__;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 [0]
 17405:     symbol=_ZN9decl_test8call_cppEi;  lookup in file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 [0]
 17405:     symbol=_ZN9decl_test8call_cppEi;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 [0]
 17405:     symbol=_ZN9decl_test8call_cppEi;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]
 17405:     symbol=_ZN9decl_test8call_cppEi;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 [0]
 17405:     symbol=_ZN9decl_test8call_cppEi;  lookup in file=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 [0]
 17405:     symbol=_ZN9decl_test8call_cppEi;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 [0]
 17405:     mutatee_out: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: _ZN9decl_test8call_cppEi (fatal)
```

Comment: Did the executable work _before_ you added the virus-code?... I mean before you edited the binary executable file?

Comment: It's not a virus code. This is a serious project, you can check at GitHub.com/dyninst. And yes it works, and the goal is to make it work after also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which parts of the binary did you change?  Just `.dynsym`?  Or `.gnu.hash` as well?  If the hash table is out of sync, `ld.so` will not find some symbols.

Comment: I parse the whole binary and rewrite it again. But I believe some dwarf parsing may be wrong or the writing of the .eh_frame section may be wrong. I'll check the gnu hash though.

Answer (score 1):

> Why would this symbol not be searched on the binary itself?

Perhaps the binary *asked* `ld.so` to not search in the binary itself?

It could do that with:

```
void *sym = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "_ZN9decl_test8call_cppEi");
```

> I parse the whole binary and rewrite it again.

It is exceedingly difficult to perform such transformation correctly on an already linked binary.

> But I believe some dwarf parsing may be wrong or the writing of the .eh_frame section may be wrong.

None of the above has anything to do with symbol resolution.

> I'll check the gnu hash though.

Failure to build the hash table would result in lookup failure, but in your case `ld.so` is *not even searching*, so the cause must be something else.

Comment: It shouldn't ask not to be searched. We have a library for binary instrumentation, so it's not difficult, it's called dyninst. The thing is that I am now changing only dwarf related code, trying now to figure what has broken in the whole process. The symbol is found and being searched but something in the middle is being done wrong.

Comment: If you change DWARF only, this will not affect ld.so symbol lookup at all.

Comment: I changed the code which parses dwarf sections and eh_frame section.

Comment: @SashaNícolas As I said above, neither DWARF nor `.eh_frame` have *anything* to do with symbol resolution. Your problem is *elsewhere*.